# Unable to suggest all values in sap.m.Input

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have implemented assisted `sap.m.Input` control in my project. I also have a value help request for the same. The binding is from an OData service.

The issue is when I type in values in the control, not all values are suggested. But if I search (filter in the `liveChange` method) in the value help dialog, I can find the desired value.

Is there some property to be set to the suggestion values in the Input control, to fetch all possible values from the OData service?

```
<Input id="idInputControl" showValueHelp="true" valueHelpRequest="onValueHelp" showSuggestion="true" suggestionItems="{/results}">
    <suggestionItems>
        <core:ListItem text="{someproperty}" additionalText="{someproperty}"/>
    </suggestionItems>
</Input>
```

This is my Input control code. I have set the data in onInit function. In the onInit function, I am able to fetch the entire data which is set to the Input control. But on typing values, only some are suggested.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model has a length limit of 100 elements.
If you want to fetch more values in your model you can increase its size limit with the `setSizeLimit` function (quick and dirty solution) or (much better) use the dynamic suggestion implementing the `suggest` event callback of the input.

[Here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputSuggestionsDynamic) in the API reference you can find a nice example of this second approach.