# Filtering SelectDialog entries - problem with setting value on Close event

Tags: sapui5

I have a problem with setting a value to an Input field after filtering the SelectDialog entries in SAP UI5.

Items from SelectDialog list are bound to the named JSON model:

```
        items="{ValueHelp>/MATGRP/results}"
```

Filtering is perfomed on the "search" event like so:

```
        var sValue = oEvent.getParameter("value");
        
        var oFilter = new Filter({ 
            filters: [ 
                new Filter("DESCRIPTION", FilterOperator.Contains, sValue),
                new Filter("CODE", FilterOperator.Contains, sValue)
            ],
            and: false
        });
        
        oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items").filter(oFilter);
```

While filtering works nicely and the List is getting refreshed - selecting a value and performing a setSelectedKey on an Input field - doesn't set any value to it. I'm setting the value like so:

```
this.sInput.setSelectedKey(oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem").getDescription());
```

If I do not use the search functionality and select the value from the list right away - the Input field gets the value populated after the Dialog is closed.

Do you have any ideas on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. This problem appeared due to the fact that I am also using "suggestionItems" aggregation and it is limited to 100 records by default. So logically an item that was found in the SuggestDialog - was not present in the suggestionItems aggregation.

I have implemented "suggest" callback for my Input control and now suggestionItems get filtered out just fine and selected item from the Suggest Dialog gets populated correctly.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162282/unable-to-suggest-all-values-in-sap-m-input) provides a solution.